# How to get iphone current screenshot from pc programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, screenshot

With android devices, we can use adb to get the current screenshot.

How about the iOS devices,is there some way to get the screenshot programmatically?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I want to  get the iphone's screenshoot ,not the mac's screenshot.

is there some way to show the iphone's screenshoot on the mac? so i can <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to cut it

Comment: do you want the screenshot of the simulator?

Comment: command + S  for Simulator Screent shot Mac machine and windows machine use Windows key + S

Answer (score 1):

You can capture iPhone current screenshot programmatically with the help of this method :

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Tanuj sharma this is not need i think  , Command + S simply fine.

Comment: Command + S is for iPhone simulator screenshot. He wants to take current view capture programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you using MAC PC then just do it

It's just as simple as command+s or File > Save Screen Shot in iOS Simulator. It will appear on your desktop by default.

Comment: i'm using MACPC and want get the iphone's screenshot which is linked by USB.  Is the some commod or mac app the get it?

Comment: Just do it press power button and home button together to capture iphone screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get a screenshot from a device connected via USB from Xcode.

1. Navigate to Debug -> View Debugging -> Take Screenshot...

[image: View Debugging]

2. Under Devices (Window -> Devices) -> Take Screenshot

[image: Devices]